# Como converter um objeto DateTime em string?

Tags: php, html5

Necessito converter um DateTime pra uma string, tenho o seguinte erro: 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string.

Imprimo em uma coluna de uma table HTML dessa forma:

```
<td align = "center"> <?php echo $linha["data_pagto"]; ?> </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com uma breve pesquisa achei a seguinte solução:

```
<td align = "center"> <?php echo date_format($linha["data_pagto"], 'd/m/y');?> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o date_format, segue um exemplo:

```
<?php $date = date_create('2013-11-23 05:06:07'); echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'); ?>
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7434dd487c2a8f1e8e283cd115f4cf27ba8e77e0

Comment: fiz exatamente isso aí e deu "date_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" e "date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given"

Comment: Não é por causa da aspas simples? O mesmo acontece com aspas duplas?

Comment: achei a seguinte solução: <td align = "center"> <?php echo date_format($linha["data_pagto"], 'd/m/y');?> </td>